# Increases row height in ListView animation

Tags: android, listview, animation

I want to apply an animation in order to highlight a specific row in a ListView.
In the animation i want the row to increase in height.

This is what i'm doing so far:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // fill out view elements
    if(isRowToHighlight) {
        ViewTreeObserver vto = convertView.getViewTreeObserver();
        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(finalConvertView, "scaleY", 1.0f, 1.8f);
                    objectAnimator.setDuration(500);
                    objectAnimator.start();
                }
            });
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

The animation works and i see the views inside the row stretch out vertically, but the row size remains the same and the view at the borders become hidden.
All layout tags in the xml have their height defined to "wrap_content"

How do i get the other rows to slide down as the highlighted row expands?